# How to use PDO prepare more than oncee in a class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, this, prepare

```
class dbConnection {

    function connect(){
        try{
            $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name", $this->db_user, $this->db_pass);
            return $this->db_conn;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}

class student{
    public $link;

    public function __construct(){
        $db_connection = new dbConnection();
        $this->link = $db_connection->connect();
        return $this->link;
    }

    public function checkLogin($username,$password){
        $query = $this->link->prepare("SELECT * FROM studentprofiles where UserName = :uname AND LogPassword = (select md5(:upassword));");
        $query->execute(array(':uname' => $username, ':upassword' => $password));
        $count = $query->rowCount();
        if($count === 1){
            $this->setSession($username);
        }
        return $count;
        $query = null;
    }

    public static function display(){
        $query = $this->link->prepare("SELECT ForeName, Surname FROM studentprofiles where UserName = :uname;"); //getting error here: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
        $query->execute(array(':uname' => self::getSession()));
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            printf (" <span id='WelcomeName'> Welcome: %s %s\n </span>",$row[0],$row[1]);
        }
        $query = null;
    }
}
```

Error using $this again to prepare another select statement, how do I use it again for another function in the same class? Thank You

Appreciate any help, really stuck on this problem

Comment: What is the repetition of the last statement supposed to mean?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: If you use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, you need to use `$row['ForeName']` and `$row['Surname']` to access the row elements. If you want to use `$row[0]` you have to use `PDO::FETCH_NUM`.

Comment: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in - $query = $this->link->prepare("SELECT ForeName, Surname FROM studentprofiles where UserName = :uname;");

Comment: That's because the `display` method is static. There's no `$this` object ina static method.

Comment: Still same error, even if I change it to PDO::FETCH_NUM

Comment: If i remove static I get another error: Strict standards: Non-static method StudentClass::display() should not be called statically

Comment: You have to call it as `$student->display()`.

Comment: Otherwise, how is it supposed to know which student's link to use?

Comment: Done that and I got another two errors:

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: student in welcome.php and Fatal error: Call to a member function display() on a non-object in welcome.php (Welcome.php is another file where I am using these functions in the student class)

Comment: Trying to use: $query = $this->link->prepare, again in another function. It works fine in checklogin, so I thought I could use it again in another function, but it doesn't work

Comment: Thank for your help Barmar, it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you can check you code and i prefer asign in to value the conection example

```
 $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

and in your function you make some one how this

```
function connect(){
        try{
            $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);  
            return $conn;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

in a complete example this:

```
$id = 5;
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase', $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);    

    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id = :id');
    $stmt->execute(array('id' => $id));

    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

please try and good luck